# Finding top 3 products in lists with sub-lists

Tags: python, algorithm, math, optimization

I am trying to find faster solution than the current brute force one, which assumes looping over all elements and is super inefficient on the larger lists.

To be more specific, I am having a list of N elements. Each of these elements has another list of variable number of elements. The goal is to find top 3 products of all lists, given that only one number from any list might be used at any time.

So for instance, if we had lists(dictionaries):

```
MAIN LIST: {'a':0.97,'b':0.88,'c':0.77}
A SUB-LIST: {'a1':0.68,'a2':0.13,'a3':0.04}
B SUB-LIST: {'b1':0.77,'b2':0.66,'b3':0.02}
C SUB-LIST: {'c1':0.99,'c2':0.92,'c3':0.13}
RESULT: 1.c*c1 2.c*c2 3.b*b1
```

I wanna get the top number from all possible products. Sorting the lists, iterating over all elements and adding them to the temporary list with top3 items is the current solution, but becomes problematic while dealing with lists having more than 1,000 elements.

Does anyone know any sort of algorithm that might be used here, given that length of each list can exceed 1000 elements?

Alternatively, if finding 3 is not possible with good time complexity - do you know any algorithm that might be used to finding e.g. top1 product between all the lists?

Comment: Is there anyway for you to change how these values are stored and how you receive them or is that out of your control?

Comment: There is a way, if needed. I am basically creating these lists/dictionaries myself. The point is of finding the top3 keys of sub-lists with a highest products.

Comment: How many keys in MAIN LIST? Like a, b, c ...? Is it only that `a` is paired with `a1` or `a2` or a3 ...?

Comment: Can they only multiply with their own kind, or can you have e.g. `c * b1`?

Comment: @ferdy The number of keys(elements) in the main list might vary. Let's assume it's N.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama No, they can only multiply with their own kind - c*c1.

Comment: I would go for a structure where you calc ahead of time the top3, when you add the sublists. Then sort the main list on top3..

Answer (score 0):

You can cut down on the multiplications by getting the top 3 of each perfix letter (using heapq nlargest)

Then apply the factors on these lists of top 3s and pick the top 3 out of those.

Something like

```
from heapq import nlargest

# group the sub list by their key letter
sub_lists = dict()
for sl in [A,B,C]:
    k = next(iter(sl))[0]
    sub_lists.setdefault(k,[]).extend(sl.items())

top3s = [ (pk,pv*main_list[k]) for k,prods in sub_lists ] 
          for pk,pv in nlargest(3,prods,key=lambda kv:kv[1]) ]

top3 = nlargest(3,top3s,key=lambda kv:kv[1])
```

*Note: You didn't provide any code or data so I could not actually test this*